# Converting many columns to binary in r

Tags: r, binary

I am trying to convert some of my columns into binary (1/0) variables.

The formula I am using is this:

```
binarydata1 <- (!is.na(freqdata1[8:37, 46:55, 62:72, 97:119, 121:133, 146:149, 155:171, 
200:256, 258:307]))+0
```

I have listed the columns in the brackets. But I am getting an error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(freqdata1, 8:37, 46:55, 62:72, 97:119, 121:133,  : 
unused arguments (97:119, 121:133, 146:149, 155:171, 200:256, 258:307)
```

Is there a good way to convert the above columns into 1/0 variables? Any help appreciated!

Comment: You need `c()` combine your column indices into a single argument. `[c(8:37, 46:55, ..., 258:307)]`

Comment: Thanks Gregor! I just realized that the new dataframe would only contain the boolean variables, Is there a way to change only those columns in the original dataframe but carry forward the other ones not being changed?

Comment: `cbind` the other columns with the binary data.

Comment: Copy the entire data frame first, `binarydata1 <- freqdata1`, then modify just those columns, `my_cols = c(8:37, ..., 258:307)`, then `binarydata1[my_cols]  <- as.integer(is.na(binarydata1[my_cols]))`. (I prefer `as.integer` to `+ 0` -- the intent is clearer)

Comment: Ah I see, got it thanks!

Comment: just to understand the code: binarydata1[my_cols[ is like saying binarydata$colname (you're just including all the column numbers listed in my_cols), then in the statement as.integer --> you're converting those columns to an integer value - because you've used is.na, it converts NA to 0 and and !is.NA to 1? Never mind, I see I had to make it !is.NA in order to convert non-missing into 1s